# Rewrite URLs with Apache (to be used in combination with mod_proxy)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, proxy, rewrite, monit

I'm using `Apache` and `mod_proxy` to provide access to the [`Monit` GUI](http://mmonit.com/monit/screenshots/) over HTTP. So far my configuration is as follows:

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /monit http://localhost:2812/
    ProxyPassReverse /monit http://localhost:2812/
```

When people go to `http://mywebsite/monit` they do get the Monit home page. However the links returned by Monit have an absolute path, which breaks the proxy which is only applied to paths starting with `/monit`. I could create a separate `vhost` just for `Monit` (e.g. `http://monit.mywebsite`) which would fix the problem, but was wondering if there was another solution.

**Q1: Is there a way to get Apache to rewrite links in HTML code to prepend whatever path is defined in the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directive?**

**Q2: If above not possible, do you see another solution than the separate `vhost` I **mentioned?**

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Your proxy setup is slightly incorrect:

it should be:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /monit http://localhost:2812
ProxyPassReverse /monit http://localhost:2812
```

notice the difference? In your setup you remove a / to many.

you could also go for

```
ProxyPass /monit/ http://localhost:2812/
ProxyPassReverse/ /monit http://localhost:2812/
```

but then requests to `http://mywebsite/monit` would not work, only to `http://mywebsite/monit/` which would be kind of inconvenient.

---

### OLD Response

Probably [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) could do what you want but as far as I know it's never the best solution.... I don't know Monit but isn't there an option in it to make it only use relative paths?